# Meaning of the word 'function' in this context?

Tags: meaning

The concept of execution environment is an essential part of the definition of software reliability. Consider that a software system supports 10 different **functions** *f1*,...,*f10*, and there are two groups of users. One group of users use only **functions** f1,...,f7, and the second group uses all the **functions**. Let **functions** *f1*,....,*f7* be fault free, but there are faults in **functions** *f8*, *f9*, *f10*.

**function**
a. the kind of action or activity proper to a person, thing, or institution; the purpose for which something is designed or exists

b. mathematical functions

c. function keys

Everyone I talked to takes the word function in this context to mean one of the above three. Which do you think is right?

Answer (score 3):

If I use this in software context, there are two possibilities:

a) "user side" functions: probably better described as functionalities, different ways a user can use the tool. Different functionalities it offers.

b) Those functionalities may be, down in the code, be implemented by different functions. Algorithmic functions I see as quite similar to mathematic funtions. (Input, function does something, output, so the function is basically a rule to process input.)

Comment: Yes - so the _functions_ OP describes really come under his definition a, but the reference to faults means we have to also consider the code with its algorithmic functions (definition b or b') that is at the heart of each sub-program.

Comment: I agree. For example a word processor you could have a:_save_, b:_edit_, c:_import_ - those would be 3 functionalities where average users would use only function a and function b and more experienced users use all 3. It is regrettable that the text is using the f1-f10, making you think it relates to the function keys on your keyboard

Comment: Actually, the function keys on the keyboard were traditionally used exactly to perform specific functions (functionalities), hence their name... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the excerpt uses the term "software" and then uses some technical notations for referring to the 'functions' (`f1-f10`) I would say that this is some kind of theoretical discussion regarding software implementation or safety-critical systems (given the use of the word 'fault').

In computer programming the words 'function', 'method' and 'procedure' (and some others) all refer to a piece of code that is referenced and executed by a computer system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine

I would say, from my computer science/IT background, that this is the sense intended in your excerpt and thus neither of your offered possibilities - the closest would be the mathematical functions which are analogous.